# Avoiding recursive notifications in Master-Detail MVVM Relationships

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a question about recursion while implementing a cascading checkbox state within an MVVM WPF three tier master-detail relationship using c#.

Let's say the relationship is <DIVISION> - <TEAM> - <PLAYER>. If I check <DIVISION>, all <TEAM> objects and all <PLAYER> objects in that <DIVISION> should be checked. If I check a <TEAM> object, all <PLAYER> objects of that <TEAM> should be checked and the <DIVISION> checkbox state should be either part-checked or checked depending on the state of the <TEAM> siblings.

To do this I've assigning a PropertyChanged event on each item within the ObservableCollection of child objects held by the parent. Each object will then respond to changes to objects in the relevant child collection. Each checkbox is bound to an IsChecked property on each model. The IsChecked property is backed by a private _isChecked variable. A ViewModel holds a reference to an observable collection of the top level <DIVISION> objects.

Scenario:

There are two <DIVISION> objects with three <TEAM> objects. Each team has three <PLAYER> objects. No objects are checked.

User changes the <TEAM> level IsChecked state from False to True using the associated checkbox.

The <TEAM> setter logic is invoked.

The <TEAM> level IsChecked setter loops through the <PLAYER> list setting the <PLAYER> level IsChecked value to the value supplied to the setter.

The first <PLAYER> IsChecked value switches to true. The <PLAYER> IsChecked state has changed and is broadcast.

The <PLAYER> state change is detected by the <TEAM> level change listener. The <TEAM> IsChecked state is now part-checked. The <TEAM> IsChecked state has changed and is broadcast.

The <TEAM> state change is detected by the <DIVISION> level change listener. The <DIVISION> state is part-checked. The <DIVISION> IsChecked state has changed and is broadcast.

The second <PLAYER> IsChecked value switches to true. The <PLAYER> IsChecked state has changed and is broadcast.

The <PLAYER> state change is detected by the <TEAM> level change listener. The <TEAM> IsChecked state is part-checked. The <TEAM> IsChecked state has not changed and is not broadcast.

The third and final <PLAYER> IsChecked value switches to true. The <PLAYER> state change is broadcast.

The state change is detected by the <TEAM> level change listener. The <TEAM> IsChecked state is checked. The <TEAM> IsChecked state has changed and is broadcast.

The <TEAM> state change is detected by the <DIVISION> level change listener. The <DIVISION> state is part-checked. The IsChecked state has not changed and is not broadcast.

The <TEAM> setter logic completes. The <TEAM> object broadcasts the state change.

The completion of the team setter logic is detected by the <DIVISION> level change listener. The <DIVISION> state is part-checked. The <DIVISION> IsChecked state has not changed and is not broadcast.

Is this the usual approach? It seems pretty inefficient and feels a bit clunky. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Sample classes are below:

```
            public class DivisionObject : ObservableObject
            {
                bool? _isSelected = false;

                public bool? IsSelected
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return _isSelected;
                    }

                    set
                    {
                        if (value != _isSelected)
                        {
                            foreach (TeamObject p in TeamCollection)
                            {
                                p.IsSelected = value;
                            }

                            _isSelected = value;

                            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                        }
                    }
                }

                public string Name { get; set; }
                public int Tier { get; set; }
                public decimal PrizeMoney { get; set; }

                public ObservableCollection<TeamObject> TeamCollection{ get; set; } 

                public DivisionObject()
                {
                    TeamCollection = new ObservableCollection<TeamObject>();
                    TeamCollection.CollectionChanged += TeamCollectionChanged;
                }

                void TeamCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                    switch (e.Action)
                    {
                        case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                            foreach (TeamObject t in e.NewItems)
                            {
                                t.PropertyChanged += t_PropertyChanged;
                            }
                            break;
                        case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                            foreach (TeamObject t in e.NewItems)
                            {
                                t.PropertyChanged -= t_PropertyChanged;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

                void t_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                    bool? isSelected = _isSelected;

                    if (e.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
                    {
                        int selectedCount = TeamCollection.ToList().Count(p => p.IsSelected == true);
                        int unselectedCount = TeamCollection.ToList().Count(p => p.IsSelected == false && p.IsSelected != null);

                        if (selectedCount == TeamCollection.Count())
                        {
                            isSelected = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (unselectedCount == TeamCollection.Count())
                            {
                                isSelected = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                isSelected = null;
                            }
                        }

                        if (isSelected != _isSelected)
                        {
                            _isSelected = isSelected;
                            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                        }
                    }            
                }
            }

            public class TeamObject : ObservableObject
            {
                bool? _isSelected = false;

                public bool? IsSelected 
                {
                    get { return _isSelected; }
                    set
                    {
                        if (value != _isSelected)
                        {                   
                            foreach (PlayerObject a in PlayerCollection)
                            {
                                a.IsSelected = value;
                            }

                            _isSelected = value;

                            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                        }
                    }
                }

                public string Name { get; set; }
                public string Ground { get; set; }
                public decimal AverageAttendance { get; set; }
                public int YearFormed { get; set; }

                public ObservableCollection<PlayerObject> PlayerCollection { get; set; }

                public TeamObject()
                {
                    PlayerCollection = new ObservableCollection<PlayerObject>();
                    PlayerCollection.CollectionChanged += PlayerCollection_CollectionChanged;
                }

                void PlayerCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                    switch (e.Action)
                    {
                        case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                            foreach (PlayerObject p in e.NewItems)
                            {
                                p.PropertyChanged += p_PropertyChanged;
                            }
                            break;
                        case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                            foreach (PlayerObject p in e.NewItems)
                            {
                                p.PropertyChanged -= p_PropertyChanged;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

                void p_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
                {
                    bool? isSelected = _isSelected;

                    if (e.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
                    {
                        int selectedCount = PlayerCollection.ToList().Count(p => p.IsSelected == true);
                        int unselectedCount = PlayerCollection.ToList().Count(p => p.IsSelected == false && p.IsSelected != null);

                        if (selectedCount == PlayerCollection.Count())
                        {
                            isSelected = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (unselectedCount == PlayerCollection.Count())
                            {
                                isSelected = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                isSelected = null;
                            }
                        }

                        if (isSelected != _isSelected)
                        {
                            _isSelected = isSelected;
                            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                        }
                    }  
                }
            }

            public class PlayerObject : ObservableObject
            {
                bool? _isSelected = false;

                public bool? IsSelected
                {
                    get { return _isSelected; }
                    set 
                    { 
                        if (value != _isSelected) 
                        { 
                            _isSelected = value;
                            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected"); 
                        }                

                    }
                }

                public string FirstName { get; set; }
                public string LastName { get; set; }
                public string Position { get; set; }

                public PlayerObject()
                {
                    _isSelected = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: This tutorial might give you some idea... http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-checkbox-control/ it's not MVVM but that's a trivial matter....

Comment: Did you try using the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events as described in the previous comment's reference? Alternatively, your `PropertyChanged` event should be raised only when the value _changes_, which should also avoid this problem. Your code example above is obviously not your actual code; it has spelling errors and has a serious `PropertyChanged` event-raising bug in it, and does not show how you are raising `PropertyChanged` in the first place. If you want help, please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem you're describing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've reworded it for greater clarification and taken the classes directly from my sample project. The approach I've taken now works so it's really more of a clarification. I'm fairly new to WPF and the MVVM pattern so I'd be interested to know what the serious PropertyChanged error is.

Comment: @monty thanks but I've pretty much got the checkbox side of it working. The slightly garbled question related more to the way the notifications were being pinged around. It seemed a bit inefficient to raise change events when they're not really needed as when the parent is updating the child.

I can disconnect the events or set some sort of bulk update flag but both approaches seem a bit clunky.